# function running that's not explicitly called

Tags: node.js

Below is virtually all of the code for a node.js app that lets you get playlists for artists if you run the command simply followed by an artists name

```
simplay the Beatles
```

From the output in the terminal, I know that the code in the ._flush method (added to the prototype of UrlsForNamesTransform)  is getting run but it's never explicitly called.  UrlsForNamesTransform extends the Transform stream in node.js, which I mention because I've seen it in other code before where a function is running without explicitly getting called (at least that I can see). Is it something about Transform or what is happening to make the code in ._flush run? 
This is the github repo for the code https://github.com/thlorenz/simplay

```
'use strict';

var urlschema = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist={{artist}}&api_key={{apikey}}&format=json';

var hyperquest =  require('hyperquest')
  , table      =  require('text-table')
  , colors     =  require('ansicolors')
  , styles     =  require('ansistyles')

var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');

var Transform = stream.Transform;

util.inherits(UrlsForNamesTransform, Transform);

function UrlsForNamesTransform (opts) {
  if (!(this instanceof UrlsForNamesTransform)) return new UrlsForNamesTransform(opts);

  opts = opts || {};

  Transform.call(this, opts);
  this._writableState.decodeStrings = false;
  this.artist = opts.artist;
  this.json = '';
}

UrlsForNamesTransform.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, cb) {
  this.json += chunk.toString();
  cb();
};

UrlsForNamesTransform.prototype._flush = function (cb) {
  var records = [];
  try {
    var o = JSON.parse(this.json);
    var artists = o.similarartists.artist;
    if (!Array.isArray(artists)) {
      this.push('Sorry, no records for "' + this.artist + '" where found, please correct your spelling and/or try another artist.');
      return cb();
    }

    artists.forEach(function (node) {
      var youtubeurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={{artist}},playlist'.replace('{{artist}}', node.name);
      var rdiourl = 'http://www.rdio.com/search/{{artist}}/artists/'.replace('{{artist}}', node.name);
      var lastfmurl = 'http://www.last.fm/music/{{artist}}'.replace('{{artist}}', node.name);
      var lastfmRadioUrl = 'http://www.last.fm/listen/artist/{{artist}}'.replace('{{artist}}', node.name);
      var urls = [
          ''
        , colors.white('  youtube:       ') + styles.underline(colors.brightBlue(encodeURI(youtubeurl)))
        , colors.blue ('  rdio:          ') + styles.underline(colors.brightBlue(encodeURI(rdiourl)))
        , colors.brightRed  ('  last.fm:       ') + styles.underline(colors.brightBlue(encodeURI(lastfmurl)))
        , colors.red  ('  last.fm radio: ') + styles.underline(colors.brightBlue(encodeURI(lastfmRadioUrl)))
        , ''
        , ''].join('\n');

      records.push([ '\n' + colors.brightYellow(node.name), colors.cyan(node.match), urls ]);
    })
    this.push(table(records.reverse()));
    cb();
  } catch (err) {
    cb(err);
  }
}


var go = module.exports = 

/**
 * Retrieves similar artists for the given artist from last.fm using the apikey.
 * Then it converts the information to display youtube.com, last.fm, rdio playlist/artist urls for each artist.
 * 
 * @name simplay
 * @function
 * @param {String} artist the artist to find similar artists for
 * @param {String} apikey the api key to be used with last.fm
 * @return {ReadableStream} that will push the url information
 */
function simplay(artist, apikey) {
  if (!artist) throw new Error('Please provid the artist that you like to get similar artist links for');
  if (!apikey) throw new Error('Please set LASTFM_API env variable to your API key: http://www.last.fm/api/account/create');

  var url = urlschema
    .replace('{{artist}}', artist)
    .replace('{{apikey}}', apikey);

  return hyperquest(url)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(new UrlsForNamesTransform({ artist: artist }))
    .on('error', console.error)
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important line is this one:

```
util.inherits(UrlsForNamesTransform, Transform);
```

What this means is that `UrlsForNamesTransform` is a subclass of `Transform`.  There is very good documentation on subclassing `Transform`, which can be found [on the node.js api site](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1).

Essentially, a subclass of `Transform` must implement `_transform` and can implement `_flush`, but is expected to never call either of those functions.  Methods in `Transform` will call them based on events on the incoming stream.